# General Form of $S^{-1}A$ - modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have been trying to show that if a ring $A$ is absolutely flat then so is the localisation $S^{-1}A$ by any multiplicative set. Now while trying to do this, I asked myself the following: Is there a description for the general form of an $S^{-1}A$ - module?

What I am trying to do to prove my original statement  is this: If $A$ is absolutely flat, consider the exact sequence

$$0 \stackrel{f'}{\longrightarrow} M' \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} M$$

of $S^{-1}A$ modules. Then suppose we tensor this with some $S^{-1}A$ module $N$ and consider the map

$$f \otimes 1: M'\otimes_{S^{-1}A } N \longrightarrow M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} N.$$

Now we know that if $N$ is flat as an $S^{-1}A$ - module, then it is flat as an $A$ - module so that the map $f|_A \otimes 1 : M' \otimes_A N \longrightarrow M \otimes_A N$ is injective. We write $f|_A$ for $f$ viewed as an injective $A$ - module homomorphism, rather than an injective $S^{-1}A$ - module homomorphism. Since localisation preserves exactness, we have that the map

$$S^{-1}(f|_A \otimes 1) : S^{-1}(M' \otimes_A N) \longrightarrow S^{-1}(M \otimes_A N)$$ is injective. If I can produce some kind of $S^{-1}A$ isomorphism between $M' \otimes_{S^{-1}A} N$ and $S^{-1}(M'\otimes_A N)$, I should be done. This is what I am trying to do, which is why I asked for a general description for what an $S^{-1}A$ - module looks like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given a commutative ring $A$ and a multiplicative set $S\subset A$ there is an equivalence of categories between:
a) $S^{-1}A$- modules $N$
b) $A$- modules $M$ for which all homotheties $s_M: M\to M: m\mapsto sm$ are bijective.

To go from a) to b), just restrict multiplication in $N$ by scalars in $S^{-1}A  $ to multiplication by scalars of $A$ *via* $A\to S^{-1}A$

To go from b) to a) keep the additive group structure on $M$  and define multiplication by scalars in $S^{-1}A$ by the formula $\frac{a}{s}\cdot m=(s_M)^{-1}(am)$

Moreover if $M,M'$ are two $S^{-1}A$-modules, the canonical morphism $$q: M\otimes _AM' \to M\otimes _{S^{-1}A} M':m\otimes m'\mapsto m\otimes m' $$ is bijective .

**Edit**
In order to address Benjamin's legitimate question in the comments, let me say a few words on the puzzling isomorphism $q$ above .
In $M\otimes _AM'$ we have the equalities $am\otimes m'=m\otimes am'\; $
In $M\otimes _{S^{-1}A}M'$ we have the **supplementary equalities** $\frac{a}{s}m\otimes m'=m\otimes \frac{a}{s}m'$, so that $q$
 is a quotient map, only surjective *a priori*.
The  pleasant result is that $q$ is an isomorphism because these supplementary equalities are automatic. Here is the heart of the calculation,  *taking place in $M\otimes _AM' $*,

$\frac{a}{s}m\otimes m'=\frac{a}{s}s\mu\otimes m'=a\mu\otimes m'=\mu\otimes am'=\mu\otimes as\mu'=s\mu\otimes a\mu'=m\otimes \frac{a}{s}s\mu'=m\otimes \frac{a}{s}m $

and, *voilà*, $\frac{a}{s}$ has jumped over $\otimes_A$ just as it would jump over $\otimes _{S^{-1}A}$ .
In other words,  the **supplementary equalities** are already valid in $M\otimes_A M'$ and no quotient is necessary: $q$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Ah, as often Mariano posted a similar answer while I was composing mine. I am happy to be in such good company!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now by the canonical morphism (I have not seen this one before) do you mean the $A$ - module homomorphism that is the identity on elementary tensors? This change of base ring issue is quite confusing to me.

Comment: Dear Benjamin, I have written an edit as an answer to  your question.

Comment: @BenjaminLim, notice that a map $M\otimes A N\to M\otimes_{S^{-1}A}N$ can *not* be the «identity on elementary tensors» because (despite the notation for them) the elementary tensors in the domain and in the codomain are different things! What *is* true is that there is such a map which sends an element of the form $m\otimes_An$ to $m\otimes_{S^{-1}A}n$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Dear Georges, I am studying your example now, however you mention of some element $\mu$. May I know what this is? Thanks,

Comment: Dear Benjamin, the element $\mu$ is just $s^{-1}\cdot m$: remember that since $M$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module, multiplication by $s^{-1}$ makes sense and of course we have $s\cdot \mu =s\cdot(s^{-1}\cdot m)=1\cdot m=m$.

Answer (score 4):

**Let me address the original question first.**

Suppose $A$ is absolutely flat. Let $B=S^{-1}A$ and let $Q$ be a $B$-module. Let us show that $Q$ is $B$-flat.

Suppose $$\tag{1} 0\to M\to N\to P\to 0$$ is an exact sequence of $B$-modules. WE want to show that $$\tag{2} 0\to Q\otimes_BM\to Q\otimes_BN\to Q\otimes_BP\to 0$$ is exact.

Now, every $B$-module is an $A$-module, and every homomorphism of $B$-modules is then automatically an homomorhism of $A$-modules. We can then view (1) as a short exact sequence of $A$-modules and $Q$ as an $A$-module. Since $A$ is absolutely flat, $Q$ is flatm and we have an exat sequence $$\tag{3} 0\to Q\otimes_AM\to Q\otimes_AN\to Q\otimes_AP\to 0.$$

You can easily check that

> if $V$ and $W$ are $B$-modules, then the obvious map $V\otimes_AW\to V\otimes_BW$ is an isomorphism.

and that this isomorphism plays nicely with maps. It follows form this that the short exact sequence (3) **is** equal to (2), so in particular the latter is exact, as we wanted.

**Next, let's deal with your subquestion.** I'll use your notation now. The displayed statement above implies that $M'\otimes_{S^{-1}A} N$ and $M'\otimes_A N$ are isomorphic $A$-modules, so in particular $M'\otimes_A N$ *is* an $S^{-1}A$-module! As a consequence applying the $S^{-1}(-)$ construction to it does not change it.

Comment: I doubt you can describe the general $S^{-1}A$-modules in any sensible way, by the way.

Comment: Would the canonical isomorphism be just the identity map? If it is then I don't get the difference between the construction $V \otimes_A W$ and $V \otimes_B W$...

Answer (score 3):

A solution is given in $\S 7.7.2$ of [my commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

It goes like this: let $N$ be a $S^{-1} R$-module.  Then there is an $R$-module $M$
such that $N \cong_{S^{-1} R} S^{-1} M := S^{-1} R \otimes_R M$.  (This is essentially what Georges is arguing for in his answer.  In my notes, I think this fact appears as an exercise.)  By definition of absolutely flat, $M$ is a flat $R$-module, and thus by the local characterization of flatness (which appears earlier in the chapter) so is $S^{-1} M$.

**Added**: I think the intermediate result used is more important than the fact that it was used to prove, and it is also relevant to the OP's question "Is there a description for the general form of an $S^{-1} A$-module?"

The key notion here is the following: if $\varphi: R \rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism, then then an $S$-module $N$ is said to be **extended from R** (via $\varphi$, although this is usually suppressed) if there is an $R$-module $M$ such that $N \cong_S M \otimes_R S$.

Off the top of my head, there are two general classes of homomorphisms $\varphi$ such that *every* $S$-module is extended from $R$:

$\bullet$ $\varphi: R \rightarrow S^{-1} R$ is a localization map (discussed above).
$\bullet$ $\varphi: R \rightarrow R/I$ is a quotient map.  (This is easy.)

However there are many important results about particular classes of $S$-modules being extended (or not!) from $R$.  For instance, suppose $R = k$ is a field, so $S$ is a $k$-algebra.  Then an $S$-module is extended from $k$ iff it is free.  In particular, when $S = k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$, a famous conjecture of Serre can be stated as: every finitely generated projective $S$-module is extended from $k$.  It would be equivalent to say that every finitely generated projective $S$-module is free, but the above formulation is indeed the path taken in all proofs of Serre's Conjecture I have seen, so this is somehow the more insightful way to say it.

Comment: Dear Pete, yes, it is exercise 7.9 on page 119 of your notes. Which I encourage all users to at least have a look at, if they want to see a  very rich and reader-friendly  online book on commutative algebra.